# BottomSheet поверх клавиатуры

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

Как создать `BottomSheet` поверх экранной клавиатуры, по примеру как в `Telegram`?

У меня в разных вариациях  получается `BottomSheet` либо под клавиатурой либо над клавиатурой, а нужно поверх.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarForTransparentStatusBar"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorActivityBackground">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/recyclerViewAttachments"
                    android:gravity="top" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewAttachments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/llAttachmentBar" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llAttachmentBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivSmile"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivRecipient"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCamera"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivAttachment"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin_8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_8dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorLabel" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivSend"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Найти аналогичное решение как у телеграм не получилось, но более-менее адекватного поведения удалось достичь с помощью `BottomSheetDialog` который сам скрывает клавиатуру и появляется на ее месте. Вот пример кода:

**MyActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_post);

    ((ViewGroup)bottomSheet.getParent()).removeView(bottomSheet);
    bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheet);
}
```

**activity_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBarForTransparentStatusBar"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorActivityBackground">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/recyclerViewAttachments"
                    android:gravity="top" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewAttachments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/llAttachmentBar" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llAttachmentBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivSmile"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivRecipient"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCamera"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivAttachment"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin_8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_8dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorLabel" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivSend"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_diploma" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>





    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@color/colorBottomSheerBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        >

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/llAddMyPhoto"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="48dp">
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="24dp"
               android:layout_height="24dp"
               android:background="@color/colorBlack"/>
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_default"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:hint="@string/label_no_info_hint_text"
               />
       </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]